# How can I use javascript to check if each Wtform RadioField has a value?

Tags: javascript, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a page with multiple [radiofields from wtforms](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/_modules/wtforms/fields/core/#RadioField). I want to only allow the user to click the submit button if they have chosen an answer for all of the radiofields. I'm using flask for the framework. Here's my javascript:

```js
<script>
    function disableSubmit () {
        console.log("function called")
        var radios = document.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"]');
        var all_questions_answered = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
            if (!(radios[i].checked)) {
                all_questions_answered = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        const buttons = ["submit"];
        if (!all_questions_answered) {
            console.log("true");
            
            buttons.forEach(element => document.getElementById(element).disabled = true);
        } else {
            console.log("false");
            
            buttons.forEach(element => document.getElementById(element).disabled = false);
        }
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        console.log("windows onload");
        disableSubmit();
    };
</script>
```

The problem is that it always disables the submit button. This is because each radiofield has multiple radios, and the user can only select one radio per radiofield. I want to check if the user has answered each radiofield, whereas my code checks if all radios have been pressed. How can I check if the user has answered each radiofield?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by counting the total number of radios, dividing it by the number of radios per radiofield, and checking if that is equal to the number of checked radios. If it is, the submit button is enabled.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to listen your radio buttons.

```js
window.onload = function() {
       for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"]').length ; i++){
     document.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"]')[i].addListener('onchange', 'checkSubmitButtons()');
    }
 };
```

After you can check all radio buttons are checked or not.

```js
function checkSubmitButtons(){
  var allRadioButtonsNotChecked = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"]').length ; i++){
    if (document.querySelectorAll('[type="radio"]')[i].checked){
       allRadioButtonsNotChecked = false;
    }else{
      continue;
    }
  document.getElementById('myButton').disabled = allRadioButtonsNotChecked
}
```

Your button:

```html
<button id="myButton" disabled>Submit</button>
```

---

The next possible problem is on Flask side. You may misunderstanding about of radio fields.

### When we use radio checks?

If we want single choice in many options, we use radio fields.

#### Why i need this information?

If your radio fields have same `name` property, you can not `check` all of them one time.